# How do I include a sidebar and a Navigation bar together using html,css and js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have got a code for navbar which is working perfectly... Also i have got the code for a collapsable side bar which is also working perfectly. But now i dont understand how to add these two together so that i get a page with navbar and sidebar together.

This is my code for navbar - (complete with html):

```html
<html>

<head>

    <title>Navbar</title>
 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
 
 
 <!--Navbar-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Navbar khatam-->
 
 <!-- Font styles -->
 <style type="text/css">
      @import "http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/dist/css/flat-ui.min.css";
   @import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";
      @import "https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css";
 </style>
 
</head>
<body style="background-color:#E6E6FA">

 <!--Navigation bar-->

 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
 
 <div class="navbar-inner"> 
 
  <!--Container class div-->
  <div class="container-fluid">

   <div class="navbar-header">
    
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     <img src="logo.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
   </div>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    
     <li><a href="#"> </a></li> <!-- TO leave some space after logo-->
     
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home </a></li>
     <li class = "dropdown">
      <a href = "#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"> Functionalities <span class = "caret"></span></a>
      <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Insurances</a></li>
       <li class="nav-divider"></li><li><a href="#">Loans</a></li>
       <li class="nav-divider"></li><li><a href="#">Card Privilages</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     
     <li><a href="#">Join Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    
    <!-- Right hand side navbar -->
    <ul class ="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
     <li><a href="customerLogin.php">Customer</a></li>||
     <li><a href="employeeLogin.php">Employee</a></li>
    </ul>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
 <!--Navbar End-->
 
  
</body>

</html>
```

Those links in the head tag - i got it by simply googling.

Also, my sidebar code is here -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Both</title>
  <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            
            body {
                font-family: Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }
            
            nav {
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 1000;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 200px;
                background-color: #036;
                transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
                transition: transform 0.4s ease;
            }
            .active-nav nav {
                transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            }
            nav ul {
                list-style: none;
                margin-top: 100px;
            }
            nav ul li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 10px 0;
            }
            
            .nav-toggle-btn {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                left: 200px;
                width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
                background-color: #666;
            }
            
            .content {
                padding-top: 300px;
                height: 2000px;
                background-color: #ccf;
                text-align: center;
                transition: transform 0.4s ease;
            }
            .active-nav .content {
                transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
            }
            
           
            
        </style>
    </head>
 
    <body>
 
 
 
        
        <nav>
            
            <a href="#" class="nav-toggle-btn"></a>
            
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            
        </nav>
        
        
        <div class="content">
            <h1>This is content</h1>
        </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        (function() {
            
            var bodyEl = $('body'),
                navToggleBtn = bodyEl.find('.nav-toggle-btn');
            
            navToggleBtn.on('click', function(e) {
                bodyEl.toggleClass('active-nav');
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            
            
            
        })();
        
        
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

But not now. how do I combine these? I want a page which will have both the top navbar and the sidebar. I have all combinations of pasting the codes but with no luck. What i have latest now - after combining these two is this -

```css
 * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            
            body {
                font-family: Open Sans, Arial, sans-serif;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }
            
            nav {
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 1000;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                width: 200px;
                background-color: #036;
                transform: translate3d(-200px, 0, 0);
                transition: transform 0.4s ease;
            }
            .active-nav nav {
                transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            }
            nav ul {
                list-style: none;
                margin-top: 100px;
            }
            nav ul li a {
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                text-align: center;
                color: #fff;
                padding: 10px 0;
            }
            
            .nav-toggle-btn {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                left: 200px;
                width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
                background-color: #666;
            }
            
            .content {
                padding-top: 300px;
                height: 2000px;
                background-color: #ccf;
                text-align: center;
                transition: transform 0.4s ease;
            }
            .active-nav .content {
                transform: translate3d(200px, 0, 0);
            }
            
  @import "http://designmodo.github.io/Flat-UI/dist/css/flat-ui.min.css";
  @import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css";
  @import "https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/animate.min.css";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Both</title>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  
  
 <!--Navbar-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <!-- Navbar khatam-->
 
 
 
    </head>
 
    <body>
 
 <!--Navigation bar-->

 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
 
 <div class="navbar-inner"> 
 
  <!--Container class div-->
  <div class="container-fluid">

   <div class="navbar-header">
    
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
     <img src="logo.jpg" alt="">
    </a>
   </div>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    
     <li><a href="#"> </a></li> <!-- TO leave some space after logo-->
     
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home </a></li>
     <li class = "dropdown">
      <a href = "#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"> Functionalities <span class = "caret"></span></a>
      <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Insurances</a></li>
       <li class="nav-divider"></li><li><a href="#">Loans</a></li>
       <li class="nav-divider"></li><li><a href="#">Card Privilages</a></li>
      </ul>
     </li>
     
     <li><a href="#">Join Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    
    <!-- Right hand side navbar -->
    <ul class ="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
     <li><a href="customerLogin.php">Customer</a></li>||
     <li><a href="employeeLogin.php">Employee</a></li>
    </ul>
    
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
 <!--Navbar End-->
 
  
 
        <!-- Sidebar nav -->
        <nav>
            
            <a href="#" class="nav-toggle-btn"></a>
            
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
            
        </nav>
        
        <!-- Sidebar Ends -->
  
  
        <div class="content">
            <h1>This is content</h1>
        </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        (function() {
            
            var bodyEl = $('body'),
                navToggleBtn = bodyEl.find('.nav-toggle-btn');
            
            navToggleBtn.on('click', function(e) {
                bodyEl.toggleClass('active-nav');
                e.preventDefault();
            });
            
            
            
        })();
        
        
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

By combining it like this, The side bar is working correctly but the top navbar is just a big white block. Nothing in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your missing an opening `style` tag just after your `<title>both</title>`. (You have a closing `/style` tag just before your nav). This will apply inline styles for the time being. You should see what you want to achieve now.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Both</title>

  <style>
    /* styles */
  </style>
</head>
```

But ultimately, you need to copy these styles into a CSS file and then link the CSS file in your HTML like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">`. That is presuming, your stylesheet is called "styles.css" and is inside a 'CSS' folder.

Have a look at the [HTML link tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_link.asp) for linking your external CSS file.

Comment: RE: I posted what i have done for combining. Errors? or any help is much appreciated. and i did css in a separate file so as to avoid the typo mentioned

Comment: Yes put the HTML in the same file and then link to external CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Divide both the sections differently. Put both in one row and give **col-2** to the sidebar side and **col-10** to the nav-bar side. This way you'll be having a side and nav-bar both side by side, you can also use the nav-bar side for creating a normal webpage. All the best!